# htaccess subdomain redirect in infinite loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, modx

I have a domain and also a subdomain which points via dns to the domain.

We want request at subdomain.domain.com to point to /a/b/page while keeping the subdomain.

eg: subdomain.domain.com goes to subdomain.domain.com/a/b/page

It currently is in an infinite loop.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a/b/page$
RewriteRule (.*) http://subdomain.mydomain.com/a/b/page [R=301,L]
```

We are using apache2 and modx as the cms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your example:

`subdomain.domain.com`

goes to (Redirects to, is rewritten as)

`subdomain.domain.com/a/b/page`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.*$
RewriteRule (.*) http://subdomain.mydomain.com/a/b/page [R=301,L]
```

There is no need to check the URI as there is NONE.

Comment: had no luck still in an infinite loop

Comment: Sorry could not be of any help. The rules work fine for main domains but in this case there is a subdomain that I can't test. Hope there is somebody that can help you.

Comment: No problem I am appreciative of your try